# How can I attach vscode to the running k8s pod not as root

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, jupyterhub

I'm using vscode with kubernetes and remote-development plugins.

I attach the vscode to a running pod (jupyter-ril) part of z2hub k8s and I run as a root, unfortunately.

```
(base) root@jupyter-ril:~# env | grep NB_USER
NB_USER=ril
```

Is there a way to run as `ril` from the `NB_USER` env variables, instead?

[image]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you re looking for security context runAsUser. Take a look at the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod) and let me know if that's what were you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding question right, 
In order to achieve this,
you can add hooks which modifies spawner config in `config.yaml` file of server deployment.

Also, if you want to mount pvc on `/home/ril` folder, changed singleuser config .

I've added below the example,

```yaml
hub:
  extraConfig: 
    custom_user : |      # to set the custom user as user in pod
      def notebook_dir_hook(spawner):
        username="ril"
        spawner.environment = {'NB_USER':username,'NB_UID':'1000'}
      c.Spawner.pre_spawn_hook = notebook_dir_hook

singleuser:
  # uid: 0   # set the nb user as root
  extraEnv:
    CHOWN_HOME: 'yes'
  storage:
    homeMountPath: /home/ril
```

The only drawback is, this will make all notebooks to have `rli` as notebook user.

Comment: The username is provided by `AzureAdOAuthenticator`, set during authentication:

       @gen.coroutine
          def pre_spawn_start(self, user, spawner):
              auth_state = yield user.get_auth_state()
              if not auth_state:
                  self.log.info(f'I AM HAVING NO AUTH_STATE')
                  return
              spawner.environment['NB_USER'] = user.name
              spawner.environment['HOME'] = f'/home/{user.name}'
```
In a case of `ril` then a pod `jupyter-ril` is spawned via jupyterhub upon authentication.

Comment: The log `Container must be run as root to set $NB_UID` I need to also set NB_UID for NFS mount. therefore I set uid within singleuser to 0

Comment: any idea how could I run the pod using as `$NB_USER` instead of root? Thanks in advance

Comment: just to clear it out, in your case NB_USER is not always going to be 'ril'? as it get modifies based on which user has logged in?

Comment: yes correct, NB_USER is set by the authenticator